# Only the first row of annotations displayed on seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

As it's usually advised, I have managed to reduce my problem to a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix = np.array([[0.1234, 1.4567, 0.7890, 0.1234],
                   [0.9876, 0, 0.5432, 0.6789],
                   [0.1111, 0.2222, 0, 0.3333],
                   [0.4444, 0.5555, 0.6666, 0]])
sns.heatmap(matrix, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

Vaguely based on Seaborn [official documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html?highlight=heatmap#seaborn.heatmap:%7E:text=values%20with%20text%3A-,sns.heatmap(glue%2C%20annot%3DTrue),-Control%20the%20annotations).

Unfortunately, unlike what would be expected (all numbers visible), I get only the numbers in the top row visible:

[image]

---

As there is not really much room for error in this one, I'm out of ideas and google/SO doesn't seem to have this question asked before. Is this a bug?

---

I am running:

```
Seaborn 0.12.2
Matplotlib 3.8.0
PyCharm 2023.1.4
Windows 10
```

Comment: Using seaborn version 0.12.2 the plot has all the annotations. What version are you on?

Comment: I ran and got the excepted output on the 0.12.2 version

Comment: Updated the post with my environment

Comment: My environment (on Windows 10) is running Matplotlib 3.7.1. The PyCharm version shouldn't affect the results. Maybe it's a bug related to a new version of Matplotlib?

Comment: This is a result of a change in matplotlib: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3478

Comment: To summarize: there was a change in Matplotlib 3.8 that is causing this issue. It will be fixed in a future version, but for now, the fix is to downgrade to Matplotlib 3.7 to get the desired results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by [@mwaskom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533576/mwaskom), it seems like it's a Matplotlib issue with a documented [solution](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3478#issuecomment-1722369068):

> Looks like problem goes away if I downgrade MATPLOTLIB to version 3.7.3.

Answer (score 16):

Just ran into the issue myself, I was on Seaborn 0.12.2. Ran `pip install seaborn --upgrade` and now have 0.13.0

Restarted vscode and annotations appeared.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, issue was for Seaborn 0.12.2, Seaborn 0.13.0 solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
!pip install seaborn --upgrade
```

In vscode works fine for me in macbook pro m1.
Relaunch after upgrade.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35532744)

Answer (score 0):

For those on earlier versions.

I am using `seaborn` version `0.13.0` and it works nicely.

[image]